# Find derivative of $y = \arccos\frac{1}{x}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find derivative of $y = \arccos\frac{1}{x}$.

My approach.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\arccos\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{|x|\cdot\sqrt{x^2-1}}\cdot\frac{1}{x^2}$$
but in my book answer is only $\frac{1}{|x|\cdot\sqrt{x^2-1}}.$ Where is my mistake?

Comment: We cannot read your mind, show us your steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiating, with the chain rule, making use of the fact that $$\frac{d}{dx}\arccos(x) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}:$$

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\arccos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}}\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\\[5pt]
&= \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}(x^2-1)}}\\[5pt]
&= \frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{|x|}\sqrt{x^2-1}}\\[5pt]
&=\frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-1}}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

It is desired to find $y'$ when:
$$\begin{align*}
  y &= \arccos{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\\
\end{align*}$$
Take the cosine on both sides:
$$\begin{align*}
  \cos{\left(y\right)} &= \cos{\left(\arccos{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\right)}\\
  \cos{\left(y\right)} &= \frac{1}{x}\\
\end{align*}$$
Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$:
$$\begin{align*}
  \frac{\mathbb{d}}{\mathbb{d}x}\left(\cos{\left(y\right)}\right) &= \frac{\mathbb{d}}{\mathbb{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
  -\sin{\left(y\right)}\; y' &= -\frac{1}{x^2}\\
  y' &= \frac{1}{x^2\sin{\left(y\right)}}
\end{align*}$$
From the Fundamental Theorem of Trigonometry, we have that:
$$\begin{align*}
  \boxed{\cos^2{\left(y\right)} + \sin^2{\left(y\right)} = 1}
\end{align*}$$
Solving for $\sin{\left(y\right)}$ and plugging it back in the expression for $y'$ yields:
$$\begin{align*}
  y' &= \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{1 - \cos^2{\left(y\right)}}}
\end{align*}$$
Use the fact that $\cos{\left(y\right)} = \frac{1}{x}$:
$$\begin{align*}
  y' &= \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2}}\\
  &= \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{x^2}}}\\
  &= \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{\frac{x^2 - 1}{x^2}}}\\
  &= \frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{|x|}\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}\\
  &= \frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}
\end{align*}$$
$$\begin{gather*}
  \boxed{y' = \frac{1}{|x|\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}}
\end{gather*}$$

Answer (score 1):

$y=\arccos\dfrac1x=\text{arcsec}x\implies 0\le y\le\pi, y\ne\dfrac\pi2$

$\implies x=\sec y\implies1=\sec y\tan y\cdot\dfrac{dy}{dx}$

If $y<\dfrac\pi2, x>0$ and  $\tan y=\sqrt{x^2-1}\implies\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac1{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Else $x<0,\tan y=-\sqrt{x^2-1},\implies\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\dfrac1{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Can you take it from here?